# Storing and accessing a pointer to an array in a std::map

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std, stdmap

The scenario is:
I am writing a framework for a particle simulation application.
I need to add various attributes to the particles, which I don't know yet and which are different per Particle. Since an attribute would be accessed and manipulate quite often in a time critical manner, I decided to store them in a plain c array. 
I would prefer to access the different kind of attributes (like pos, vel, force, etc.) by name.
So I decided to use a `std::map<const std::string,double*>` to store the floating point attributes.

So to my question. I try to store particle attribute values as following

```
double* attr = new double[3 * 10];
std::map<std::string,double*> doubleAttributes3d;
doubleAttributes3d.insert(std::make_pair("pos", attr));

for(int64_t i = 0;i<10;++i)
{
    *(doubleAttributes3d["pos"] + 3 * i) = 1.0;
    *(doubleAttributes3d["pos"] + 3 * i + 1) = 2.0;
    *(doubleAttributes3d["pos"] + 3 * i + 2) = 3.0;
}

double * ptr = doubleAttributes3d["pos"];
for(int64_t i = 0;i<10;++i)
{
    cout << *(ptr + 3 * i) << " ";
    cout << *(ptr + 3 * i + 1) << " ";
    cout << *(ptr + 3 * i + 2) << endl;
}
```

Which causes a segfault.
In particular, everytime when I try to access elements of the array.

1. Is there a possibility this can ever work?
   (I had never the need of using a map before, maybe I simply produce an error due to syntax mistakes...)  Or in other words why can't I access the memory address which I stored into the map?
2. Would there be another/better(/actually working) way of storing an unknown number of arrays and give them a "name" in order to access and manipulate them later?

I know there were similar questions asked around here but none of the answers worked out for me.

Comment: I think you mean `i < 10` instead of `i < 3 * 10` in the loop conditions.

Comment: oh yes of course, corrected it in the question

Comment: Why not use a `vector` instead of a raw array?

Comment: I was also thinking about it, since it should be expandable during simulationtime. But since I need to reorder the particles later quite often I need to copy them either way, and since I didn't which overhead (in a perfomance manner) comes along with the vector class i decided to use plain c arrays

Comment: So you have concluded that std::vector incurs an unacceptable performance hit compared to plain arrays, and you have decided to store pointers to these arrays in  std::map?

Comment: I know this is kind of schizophrenic. I'd like to also omit the std::map but I didn't found a way around it. (Which concerns my 2 question)
And the std::map is not that critical, since i usually access an particle attribute type only once or twice per step but i have to access the array about 100 million times per Timestep...

Comment: I edited the codesample to make it a bit clearer how i want to access the attributes later

Comment: There's [no evidence](http://ideone.com/sbn03K) of a segmentation fault. Please post an MCVE. Besides, `std::vector` incurs **no** overhead. Zero.

Comment: BTW, did you remember to `delete[]` the pointer?

Comment: I suggest (1) use `struct Point3d { double x[3]; };` to avoid hand-calculating indices (2) use `std::vector<Point3d>` (3) **profile** both plain array version and this version to make sure there's no performance hit attributable to either `std::vector` or `struct Point3d`. Also @Dugi is right, use an enum if you can, and a plain array (or std::array).

Comment: And BTW if your attributes have vastly different physical meaning, you probably need different code to process each kind of attribute. This probably means you are better off creating a separate class for each attribute. Which will naturally have its own attribute data storage (an array of double, or whatever). Then you will store some container of `unique_ptr<AttributeBase>` instead of your present attribute map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question's awnser:**
I tried to run it and it run without issues, producing the expected results. I used valgrind on it and it reported no undefined behaviour. Your error must be elsewhere or it was fixed when you changed the bounds of the for cycle.

**Second question's awnser:**
How many variables you have there? std::map is useful only if there is a lot of variables and most of them are unset for most particles.
In most cases, it's much more comfortable and far faster to index the properties with an enum, that can be used to address a standard c array. For example:

```
enum pp {
   POS,
   VEL,
   FORCE,
   CHARGE,
   MASS,
   ELECTRON_CONFIGURATION,
   ppMax
 }
 double* particles[1000][ppMax];
 particles[0][POS] = new new double[3 * 10];
 // et cetera
```

I benchmarked a similar issue and the difference in speed was significant, even if I had to set all unused pointers to nullptr. I don't think that the additional spacial complexity matters much in this case.

Comment: Thanks alot, yes i found out that it was a problem with the object generation in combination with googletest. (Since I am currently writing the core of my app and I do not have a running version, I was writing tests...) The data_object wasn't initialized in a proper way...